# Create a sequence in R with that alternatively repeats

Tags: r, sequence

My homework asks me to create a sequence like this.

```
(1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6, 6, . . . , 50, 50)
```

I'm a newbie to R so would really appreciate your help

Comment: Which functions have you learned that might be relevant?

Comment: "give me the code" questions are usually not well received here. That said, there are many approaches to such questions. Here's a funny one `1:25 %x% c(0, 1, 1) * 2 + 1:25 %x% c(1, 0, 0) * 2 - c(1, 0, 0)` that shows R's vectorized nature

Comment: I understand Donald, just started my first lesson with R today on vector and this is an exercise on rep() function

Answer (score 0):

You can use `rep` and alternate the number of repeats. Check `?rep` for more information.

```r
rep(1:50, ifelse(seq(1:50) %% 2, 1, 2))
```

Or, with two `rep`s:

```r
rep(1:50, rep(1:2, 25))
rep(1:50, rep(1:2, length.out = 50))
```

Comment: Or `rep(1:50, rep(1:2, length.out = 50))`.

Comment: yup this is exactly what I need

Answer (score 0):

Short code using integer division:

```
2:76%/%1.5
```

This will return a `numeric` vector.